# ej-autocomplete passing text not value

Tags: autocomplete, syncfusion

I am trying to write a control that takes a list of names, allows the user to select from this list and then posts back the username for the name that has been selected.

Firstly, I used a Syncfusion ejDropDownList control to accomplish this, where the code I used was:

```
<ej-drop-down-list id="UserList" datasource="(IEnumerable<User>)ViewBag.Users" ej-for="Username">
    <e-drop-down-list-fields text="Name" value="Username" />
</ej-drop-down-list>
```

This works fine and when I submit the form, the Username field is bound correctly in the associated model.

Since there are too many names in the list to realistically use a drop-down list, an autocomplete control is preferable.

However, when I implemented the control in the following manner:

```
<ej-autocomplete id="UserList" datasource="(IEnumerable<User>)ViewBag.Users" ej-for="Username" filter-type="Contains">
    <e-autocomplete-fields text="Name" value="Username" />
</ej-autocomplete>
```

Then the 'Username' value in the model is bound to the 'Name' field.

Is anyone familiar with Syncfusion controls who can tell me how I can bind the selected value (as opposed to the selected text) to the 'Username' column successfully?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion Autocomplete not have a field type of value. You can also use **Key** field for your scenario.`<ej-autocomplete id="UserList" datasource="(IEnumerable<User>)ViewBag.Users" ej-for="Username" filter-type="Contains">
    <e-autocomplete-fields text="Name" key="Username" />
</ej-autocomplete>`

refer the documentation link: https://help.syncfusion.com/aspnetmvc/autocomplete/data-binding

Comment: Thanks @karthik!

How do I then use this 'Username' key to populate my model or how can I use this key in my controller class?